# Less verbose Visitor implementation in C#

Tags: c#, overloading, visitor-pattern

Suppose you have an abstract `BaseClass` and some derived classes and that you need to visit a `List<BaseClass>` with a `Visitor`. The code would be:

```
class Visitor
{
    public void Visit(Derived1 visitable) { /*do something*/ }
    public void Visit(Derived2 visitable) { /*do something*/ }
    public void Visit(Base visitable) { thrown new InvalidOperationException(); }
    //other derivatives
}

class Base
{
    public virtual void Accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    //override is mandatory to have Visit(Derived1 visitable) called
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    //override is mandatory to have Visit(Derived2 visitable) called
    public override void Accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
}
```

Then you can use all this stuff in a method like:

```
var baseClassList = new List<BaseClass>();
//fill baseClassList somehow

var visitor = new Visitor();

foreach(var visitable in baseClassList)
    visitable.Accept(visitor);
```

I think this is a bit too much for a simple dispatching of some operations on different derived classes.

Also, it is counter-intuitive that the chain starts from calling `Accept` and not `Visit`.

Also, if you add a new `Derived3` class, you always have to do 2 things: a new overload in the `Visitor` AND the override of the `Accept` method in the new derived class. Often you forget the second point, getting a runtime error, and other annoying things.

**I'm looking for some simpler and less verbose and more secure implementation of a `Visitor` pattern in C#. Is it possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 2 hypotheses:

1. You can use C# 4.0 or more recent
2. `BaseClass` is abstract and there isn't a "default" behavior for `BaseClass` (i.e., the `Visitor` has a different specific behavior on EVERY derived)

I found a solution:

```
class DynamicVisitor
{
    public void Visit(BaseClass b)
    {
        Visit((dynamic)b);
    }

    public void Visit(Derived1 b) { /*do something*/ }

    public void Visit(Derived2 b) { /*do something*/ }
}
```

And you use it this way:

```
var baseClassList = new List<BaseClass>();
//fill baseClassList somehow

var visitor = new Visitor();

foreach(var visitable in baseClassList)
    visitor.Visit(visitable);
```

This way, you don't need any `Accept` method, nor its overrides on the visited classes.
You only need to write the overloads on the `Visitor`.
The overload `Visit(BaseClass b)` ensures that any passed parameter derives at least from the `BaseClass`, but the `dynamic` cast makes the `Visitor` to choose the specific overload at runtime.
Obviously, if an instance is exactly of type `BaseClass`, you have an infinite recursive call of `Visit(Base b)`, and that's because I supposed that `BaseClass` is abstract: this way you cannot have an instance of that exact type.

---

### **EDIT:**

I made some performance tests with this approximate load:

1. A `BaseClass` and 17 `DerivedClasses` implementing an `IVisitable` interface;
2. a list with a milion instances of `BaseClass` to visit;
3. a `ClassicVisitor` and a `DynamicVisitor` both implementing an `IVisitor` interface;
4. All the `Accept` methods call only the `Visit` method and all the `Visit` methods are empty, to maximize the measured difference in time.
5. Time measured with a `Stopwatch` in both Debug and Release mode.

**Result: the `DynamicVisitor` is more than 10 times slower** (~5/600ms against ~50ms).

So, this solution is suitable for contexts in which you have a small amount of calls to make on the visitor.